# C# and unity. Moving an object to a target and destroy target once we're close

Tags: c#, unity3d

This is my first ever c# script. I have played around a little and I think this is some proper c# code. Since it's my very first c# ever, I'm assuming there's a few mistakes, things that could be better, bad conventions and such. If you see any, please let me know so I can improve!

```
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject target;  
    private GameObject player; // creating a variable for the player object
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (target != null) { // if the target is already destroyed, we don't have to do anything anymore
            player = this.gameObject; // the script is attached to the player
            

            // Here I expected I could get the NavMeshAgent component via something like player.NavMashAgant. 
            // I do the same later for target.transform. 
            // Is there a reason this component is not accessible via dot notation?
            GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().destination = target.transform.position; // set the players destination as the targets potion. It starts moving automatically. 
            if (AreClose(player, target)) { 
                Destroy(target);
            }
        }
    }

    private static double Distance(GameObject a, GameObject b)
    {
        Vector3 aPos = a.transform.position;
        Vector3 bPos = b.transform.position;
        // A really long line.. What is the convention to make this more readable?
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(aPos.x - bPos.x, 2) + Math.Pow(aPos.y - bPos.y, 2) + Math.Pow(aPos.z - bPos.z, 2));

    }

    private static bool AreClose(GameObject a, GameObject b)
    {
        double result = Distance(a, b);
        if (result < 2.5) // random magic number for now
        {
            return true;
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review!

I'm not too familiar with Unity, so I can't really comment or offer advice on Unity-specific things.

There are still a few places where I feel like your code could be improved however.

## Whitespace

While I generally prefer to keep my code not too dense, I recommend never having more than one blank line in a row (except *maybe* if you want to separate a block of imports or `using`s from the rest of the code); some editors will even automatically remove any consecutive blank lines when you format your document.

Similarly, that blank line at the end of your `Distance()` method doesn't serve any purpose, so I would just remove it, or maybe move it right below your `aPos` and `bPos` declarations.

## `AreClose()` method

Your `AreClose()` method could be rewritten in a much shorter and cleaner way, like so :

```
private static bool AreClose(GameObject a, GameObject b)
{
    double result = Distance(a, b);
    return (result < 2.5); // random magic number for now
}
```

That's because the expression `result < 2.5` itself evaluates to a boolean, so there's no need to check whether its value true or false, you can simply return it.

You could further shorten it to...

```
private static bool AreClose(GameObject a, GameObject b)
{
    return Distance(a, b) < 2.5; // random magic number for now
}
```

...since, in my opinion, the variable `result` doesn't add anything to the readability or the clarity of the code. Seeing `Distance(a, b) < someMagicNumber` is clear enough on its own.

You could go even further and take advantage of C#'s expression body definitions, like so

```
private static bool AreClose(GameObject a, GameObject b) => Distance(a, b) < 2.5; // random magic number for now
```

...which doesn't look too great here because of that comment. I would recommend you put that magic number into a `const` variable, either declared inside `AreClose()` or as a class variable. This will make your code easier to modify in the future, and also allows you to give it a meaningful name like `MIN_DISTANCE`.

```
private static bool AreClose(GameObject a, GameObject b) => Distance(a, b) < MIN_DISTANCE;
```

## `Distance()` method

Like I said earlier, I'm not too familiar with Unity, but I'm pretty sure it has a built-in method for computing the distance between two vectors, like so `Vector3.Distance(aPos, bPos)`.

There's nothing inherently wrong with doing it yourself if you're just trying to learn and get familiar with a new language or concept, but if you're looking for optimal performance or accuracy, I would recommend making sure there isn't already a function that does what you need before trying to reinvent the wheel -although in this specific case it's probably not too important.

Additionally, I would avoid using `Math.Pow()` when you only want to square a number, as it's quite an expensive operation compared to simply doing `(aPos.x - bPos.x) * (aPos.x - bPos.x)`. This is because `Math.Pow()` needs to be able to handle non-integer exponents and (probably) uses Taylor series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) to compute powers for arbitrary exponents, even if your exponent happens to be `2`. So you can just compute the square yourself, which should significantly improve performance.

You could also create a `DistanceSquared()` method, and compare it with `MIN_DISTANCE * MIN_DISTANCE`, which is equivalent to comparing `Distance()` and `MIN_DISTANCE`. This allows you to avoid using `Math.Sqrt()`, which is, again, a rather slow operation. Then you can rewrite `Distance()` like this, if you still want it :

```
public static double Distance(GameObject a, GameObject b) => Math.Sqrt(DistanceSquared(a, b));
```

Comment: I understand everything you've said except the last part. I understand the usecase for a `DistanceSquared` and it leading to not needing to use `Math.Sqrt`. However, in the last example you use `Math.Sqrt` anyway. Am I misunderstanding after all?

Comment: I simply meant that, if you still want to have a `Distance()` method in addition to `DistanceSquared()` (maybe you want to draw a circle around your `Mover` that shows its range, who knows?), you can make it so just returns the square root of `DistanceSquared()`, without having to reimplement all the calculations already done in `DistanceSquared()`. Is that clear? In short, don't rewrite code you're already written.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has built in support for measuring distance. If I remember correctly it would look something like this.

```
return (a.transform.position-b.transform.position).Length
```

You could also save on performance by squaring the radius to check instead of `sqrt` ing the distance.

Branches are uneccessary in this function.

```
private static bool AreClose(GameObject a, GameObject b)
{
    return Distance(a, b) < 2.5;
}
```

The unity inspector has really good support for editing primitive variables if you make them public.

```
public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float destroyRadius = 2.5f;
...
```

```
GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>()
```

GetComponent is kind of slow. Assigning it in `Start()` would help performance.